# How to convert string json to url format in android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to make a slider with this [tutorial](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) and it works very good. But when I try to get the image url from JSON with volley this url does not work. I want to convert the string to url, but my code is not working.

```
img1 = obj.getString("image_1");
URL myURL1 = new URL(img1);
```

Comment: post your complete json parsing code and error details if there are any

Answer (score 1):

Add `app/gradle.app` as a dependencies

`compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'`

Now you need to create a `Object.class` according to your Json object. And all `key` names should same as your `Object.class`

Eg: `Json` object:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "message": "This is example"
  "url": "http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/"
}
```

`Class` object:

```
public class ExampleObject {
    public long id;
    public String message;
    public String url;
}
```

Then in your `Activity.java`:

```
//jsonObj is your JSON object
ExampleObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj, ExampleObject.class);
```

Now all the values are saved into your Object class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the url of the image retrieved in an imageview you can pass the string to an image processing library, for exemple Glide. Here's a good tutorial on how to set it up and use it: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK contains a very useful `Uri` class. It exposes a `Builder` that can be used for property URL building (instead of string concatenation, that you are using). It also has a `Uri.parse()` method, that can create an instance from a `String`.